# Saved Call Log Doesn't appear in Call Log Case Feed

Tags: opencti

How do I get my Tasks that are created via the [Open Cti Save Log method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_savelog.htm) to appear in the Case Feed as a Call log? Presently the tasks I create appear but they show up as Tasks and not Calls.

Here is an example of my safeLog method call:

sforce.interaction.saveLog('Task', 'ActivityDate=2016-02-18 13:29:24&Type=Call&Subject=Testing Subject&Status=Completed&WhoId=003i000000IP4VTAA1&WhatId=500i000000ByGvLAAV&Description=Some call notes&CallDisposition=No Answer', callback);

What am I missing here? I am thinking I need to use CallObject but not matter what I set there it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after all. This is not explained very well but the CallObject is not the call centre but rather the unique id of the call. If you set this then it will show up as a call in the feed.

I am wondering how I can get a manually logged call to show up without setting this field though? If I don't have a unique call id because they are manually logging a call (Just like the log a call button). How can I get this to show up?

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new question, or edit your original question, instead of asking a followup question in your answer

Comment: What feed are you talking about? The 'activity history' related list?

Comment: That's probably true. I finally got an answer for this though. Turns out you have to set the CallObject and the Call Type in order for the call to show up. There is no way around this. I think that's a mistake but that is what it is. You have to set Internal, Outgoing, or Incoming.